# Height and ability to gain muscle mass

Tags: height, muscle-growth

I was reading [this](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5252/working-out-do-taller-people-have-it-harder) post and I came up with a question that was not asked in it.

In particular, I wondered if **taller people have the ability to gain more muscle in the same amount of time than shorter people?**

It seems highly implausible to me that a 7ft person cannot gain more lean mass than a 5ft person in the same amount of time.

A possible reason behind this could be that tall people might have **more muscle fibers** (not larger) to begin with due to their size so their total rate of growth will be higher.

Note that I am not saying that the statement above is indeed true. I am just giving out a possible reason which if true, it could lead to taller people having a higher rate of growth.

I could not find research on that however, so anyone who knows something on this matter is welcome.

Comment: First, this is not a forum about complaining. I simply set a question. The way you started your comment was very improper. Moreover, I didn't say that they do have in fact more muscle fibers. I mentioned the word "probably". I have found no research with serious results on that matter. I will try to reform my question and make it more clear.

Comment: I don't believe it.  I explicitly stated that I am not saying that it is true. My intuition says that there is a possibility that larger guys have more fibers. Hence, I have a reason to believe that it might be true. It is part of the question. I state that this hypothesis is relevant to my question and if true it could lead my first hypothesis also being  true. Hence, any info about this question could also provide info about the first. Seems like someone does not want it to be true or even explore it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. For some reason I ignored part of your edit

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking there is a misconception that smaller people build muscle faster and not vice versa like you say.In reality tall short or average doesn't matter they all can build the same amount of muscle mass given they have the same training program nutrition and genes which is practically impossible that's why no studies exist about that matter.That's just my conlusion after reading many articles.Half of those claim that height matters the other half claims the opposite.Until a research i done we'll never know for sure.